# How to edit a nclob column using Sql Developer

Tags: oracle, nclob

I can't edit a nclob column data type in Oracle Database using SQL Developer :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Left side of the screenshot says that you executed `SELECT` statement which results in some rows. `CONFIG` (which is `CLOB`, right?) can't show all data it contains in a single line, so you have an option to do so by clicking the *pencil* button - which is what you did, as showed on the right side of the screenshot.

Meaning: you are viewing `SELECT` statement's result, you can't *edit* it. If you want to edit column's contents, go to Object Navigator, find that table, go to the "Data" node and perform edit there.

What you wanted to do is to edit this (executed in SQL*Plus):

```
SQL> select * From dept;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON
```

You can't edit anything here, it is just the result of a query. `UPDATE` would do it, or - if you used GUI (and yes, you do) - go to "Data" tab and do it there.